# Height carosuel-item bootstrap 4.6

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, carousel

I need some help with this issue,
Y have this component on angular 14 with bootstrap v4.6:

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100 d-sm-none" src="/assets/headers/unite-header-movil.png" alt="First slide">
        <img class="w-100 logo-header d-none d-sm-block" src="/assets/headers/Pokemon-Unite-main.webp">
        <div class="logo-unite-header row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-5 col-sm-3 d-none d-sm-block">
              <img class="w-100 logo-header" src="/assets/headers/unite-logo.png">
          </div>
        </div>  
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100 d-sm-none" src="/assets/headers/header.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        <img class="d-none w-100 d-sm-block" src="/assets/headers/header-medium-up.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        <div class="logos-header row justify-content-center w-100 m-0">
            <div class="col-5 col-sm-3">
                <img class="w-100 logo-header" src="/assets/headers/pokemon-scarlet-logo-medium-up.webp">
            </div>
            <div class="col-5 col-sm-3">
                <img class="w-100 logo-header" src="/assets/headers/pokemon-violet-logo-medium-up.webp">
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
</div>
```

The classes .logos-header and .logo-unite-header are translated vertically with transform: translateY().

And the problem is that the item-carousel that contains them is setted counting with their heights, but i don't want this(I want the height of item carousel to be the heigth of the image sibling these classes).

And if I set height: 0 and overflow: visible, the height of .item-carousel is the good one but the elements inside are not visibles.

Help! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It was really very simple.

I only had to give absolute value to those rows.

Lockdown example that just needs a calm look

```
.logos-header{
    transform: translateY(-150%);
    position: absolute;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .logos-header{
        transform: translateY(-100%);
        position: absolute;
    }

    .logo-unite-header{
        transform: translateY(-280%);
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```